# Is there a device that can view 4 computer images on a monitor?

Tags: monitors

I know there are monitors capable of displaying 2 or 4 inputs at a time but Is there a device that can view 4 computer images on a monitor?

Comment: A 5th computer receiving streams, VNC, or HDMI inputs from the other 4 could be used to do this. Or even one of the 4 computers could take the streams/inputs of the other 3 plus its own primary display then display a 4-screen composition on a secondary display. This can all be accomplished with livestreaming software like [OBS](https://obsproject.com/).

Comment: Hi @Romen! Thanks for your suggestion. How can a mother computer capture video streams from other computers?
If you are referring to the desktop remote method, this method is very slow. In addition, this method consumes a great deal of system resources.

Comment: By using [a PCIe capture card like this one](https://www.avermedia.com/professional/product/ce314_hn/overview), you can compose a "scene" with the 4 HDMI inputs in a streaming program like [OBS](https://obsproject.com/). Then that "scene" can be displayed on a monitor plugged into that computer. Like I mentioned before, if one of the 4 PCs is fast enough, you could use a 2nd monitor and not need a 5th PC for this. Yes, using remote desktop or "streaming" would use more resources on all 4 computers, but that is another solution that only requires software.